# Laravel: Detect token mismatch in controller

Tags: laravel

I notice that on my site, once a user has stayed on a page too long (usually takes a few hours), AJAX post requests will return the JSON `message` of `CSRF token mismatch.`

Is there any way I can detect that in the controller so I can return a proper error message (I realize I can do this in the front end logic but it would be nice to know)?

Comment: Not likely; there's a middleware that catches `CSRF` errors before you even get to the controller. For me, front-end logic was the way to go; add a script that, after 2 hours of inactivity displays a alert/modal/etc. that says "You need to refresh the page before continuing" (or similar)

Comment: Alright. I'll do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Route filters to do that.

From laravel documentation:

> Route filters provide a convenient way of limiting access to a given route, which is useful for creating areas of your site which require authentication. There are several filters included in the Laravel framework, including an auth filter, an auth.basic filter, a guest filter, and a csrf filter. These are located in the app/filters.php file.
>
> **Note: Filters are disabled when the application environment is testing.**

First define Route filter in your Service Provider:

```php
Route::filter('csrf', function(){
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token')) {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

Then in your route you can attach `before` parameter, For example:

```
Route::get('user', [
    'before' => 'csrf', 
    'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'
]);

// Ore if you have functional route

Route::get('user', [
    'before' => 'csrf', 
    function(){
        return 'Response here';
    }
]);
```

Hope this helps you.